# Creating custom function Left()

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function

I have data originating from a central registry for drilling wells. Each well may have a date attached to it and I want to create a layer which differentiates wells drilled by a certain year. Problem is the data are stored in a String format and it can look like `yyyy` or `yyyymm` or `yyyymmdd` or `null`.

So how can I create a function that takes the 4 leftmost characters if any and convert into a number like `To_integer(Left4(MyValue))` so I can filter it out by those older than a certain year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a function already exists with QGIS expressions: `left( 'yourstring' , 4)` returns `'your'`. Use it with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#vector-field-calculator).

- See [documentation for `left`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=left#left)

Use  `to_int(left( 'yourstring' , 4)` to convert to an integer: `to_int(left ('2021-10-04', 4))` returns: `2021` as integer.

- See [documentation for `to_int`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=left#to-int)

---

You could also use `to_date` to format your string as date: `to_date(left ('2021-10-04', 4),'yyyy')` returns `2021-01-01` in date format. To retrieve the year, use `year`: `year (to_date(left ('2021-10-04', 4),'yyyy'))` returns `2021`.

- See [documentation for `to_date`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#to-date) and [documentation for `year`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#year).